# Average of rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

here my table
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmt8B.png)

I want to find the average of MTK+IPA+PJOK
[table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLm0u.png)

with this code

```
SELECT induk, nama, kelas,
       SUM(if (kdmapel=“111”,ratarata,0)) as MTK,
       SUM(if (kdmapel=“112”,ratarata,0)) as IPA,
       SUM(if (kdmapel=“115”,ratarata,0)) as PJOK,
       ((MTK+IPA+PJOK)/3) as NAR
from nilai
WHERE kelas=1 and semester=“ganjil”
group by induk
```

but it doesn't work, the error said

> #1054 - Unknown column 'MTK' in 'field list'

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 2):

The MTK, IPA and PJOK are calculated from group functions.
So they can't be used directly like that.

One way is to wrap it all in a sub-query, then calculate NAR in the outer query.

However, their calculation is quite simple and similar.
So the calculation for NAR isn't much harder.

```
SELECT induk, nama, kelas,
       SUM(if(kdmapel='111',ratarata,0)) as MTK,
       SUM(if(kdmapel='112',ratarata,0)) as IPA,
       SUM(if(kdmapel='115',ratarata,0)) as PJOK,
       (SUM(if(kdmapel IN('111','112','115'),ratarata,0))/3) as NAR
FROM nilai
WHERE kelas=1 and semester='ganjil'
GROUP BY induk
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are referencing the alias name and it doesn’t know what that is.

Either write it as a CTE and then add the alias columns together or first store the results in a temp table and then add them.

Something like this

```
;With myCte as
(

SELECT induk, 
       nama,
       kelas,
       SUM(if (kdmapel='111',ratarata,0)) as MTK, 
       SUM(if (kdmapel='112',ratarata,0)) as IPA, 
       SUM(if (kdmapel='115',ratarata,0)) as PJOK
      from nilai WHERE kelas=1 and semester='ganjil' 
      group by induk

)
Select *,
 ((MTK+IPA+PJOK)/3) as NAR
  From myCte
```